# 'Minimize' a ViewController that user can access at any time anywhere in the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewstate, user-interaction

I need some hints or suggestions on an issue.

What I want to do is to 'Minimize' a `UIViewController` like the 'message circles' in old facebook messages. So that the user can continue using the app and just move the circle to anywhere on the screen and then tap it to open it up and continue working from there.

The minimized `UIViewController` is suppose to be a `UIWebView` and I want the user to be able to continue working from whatever state the webpage was in.

I know one is suppose to add code here but I more want some pointers on where to start and how to think or possibly some suggested codesnippets or links.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks

edit: Thanks Moti. Ok so I will Not be using storyboard but do do everything programmatically.
I will have it not fully hidden but 'minimized' as an ontop circle to be accessed to just by tapping it anywhere from in the app.

Trick14, I will have a check. tnx

Comment: Do you mean the chat head? There's a good source on [github](https://github.com/brutella/chatheads)

Answer (score 0):

If its part of navigation controller you can keep strong reference to it somewhere, so when you pop it out it will stay alive. And when you need it you can push it again.

If you can describe some more details regarding how you show/hide and if its part of storyboard or built in runtime, the community will be able to be more specific regarding solutions.

If you look into `UIViewController` you will see

`addChildViewController:`

`removeFromParentViewController`

`willMoveToParentViewController:`

`didMoveToParentViewController:`

You can play around with those to achieve what you need, for example when you detect that the "overlay" controller removed from parent view controller you could push it back in the method `didMoveToParentViewController:` of the the other controller.

Yes, there is some management to be done, but it is possible.
I will try to make some working example with dummy views.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the view controller to be topmost always (when "circled")?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Base View Controller which is inherited by every ViewController in your app. Declare the functions in it. And you can directly access these functions in any of your base class. Or simply hide or show your view anywhere in your app.